# Como puedo pasar parametros al momento de importar un excel con Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Intento enviar un parametro para que se puede anexar a la importacion del excel a la base de datos, mas especifico necesito enviar el numero de semana asi que hago esto

```
$now = Carbon::now()->week();
Excel::import(new DetailsNominaImport($now), $request->file('noi'));
```

Y en la clase `DetailsNominaImport` lo recibo de este modo

```
 public $now;
    
        public function __construct($now)
        {
            $this->$now = $now;
        }
```

Pero al momento de intentar acceder desde la funcion `collection`(intento acceder asi `$this->now`) me arroja `null`, al hacer un `dd()`,
me arroja lo siguiente

```
App\Imports\DetailsNominaImport {#1416 ▼
  +now: null
  +"34": 34
}
```

Uso la ultima version de Laravel Excel y de laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el contructor de la clase tenia mal esta parte

```
//anterior
    public $now;
        
            public function __construct($now)
            {
                $this->$now = $now;
            }
```

SOLUCION

```
public $now;
        
            public function __construct($now)
            {
                $this->now = $now; // errro en en linea
            }
```

Comment: consulta, de esa manera pudiste insertar campos adicionales en el import del excel?

Comment: es correcto, de esta manera funciona apropiadamente