# Problema con pasar parametros a laravel-excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Explico la situación:

Tengo esta ruta

```php
Route::get('peajes/exportefectivodia/', [App\Http\Controllers\InformesController::class, 'exportefectivodia'])->name('exportefectivodia');
```

El controlador la función exportefectivodia es:

```php
public function exportefectivodia() 
{
    return Excel::download(new EfectivodiaExport, 'excel_efectivo_dia.xlsx');
}
```

Y por último `EfectivodiaExport`

```php
class EfectivodiaExport implements FromView
{

    public function view(): View
    {   
        $fecha = Carbon::now();
        $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
        
        $fecha1 = Carbon::now();
        $fecha1 = $fecha1->format('d-m-Y');

        $peajes = Peaje::whereDate('created_at',$fecha)
        ->where('tipo_acceso','Efectivo')
        ->get();
        //$peajes = Peaje::all();
        //dd($peajes);
        return view('informes.diarioefectivo', compact(['peajes']));
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no logro pasarle parámetros desde otra pagina a este ultimo controlador.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Creería que se puede declarar una propiedad publica y asignarle el valor en el constructor. Esta pregunta es sobre importar, pero supongo que será lo mismo para exportar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383273/como-puedo-pasar-parametros-al-momento-de-importar-un-excel-con-laravel-excel

Comment: voy a revisar muchas gracias, por el momento mande los datos a una tabla y el export busca por defecto el registro en la tabla(que es único por usuario), no se que tan buena practica es, pero hasta acá funciona.